# Как в 1С правильно сделать условия для двойного цикла?

Tags: 1с

Есть такой код:

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст =
"ВЫБРАТЬ
 |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка КАК Ссылка,
 |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.Номер КАК Номер,
 |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации КАК ПодразделениеОрганизации,
 |РегСведПерв.ИнвентарныйНомер КАК ИнвентарныйНомер
|ИЗ
   |Документ.ИнвентаризацияОС.ОС КАК ИнвентаризацияОС,
     |ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрСведений.ПервоначальныеСведенияОСБухгалтерскийУчет.СрезПервых КАК РегСведПерв
     |ПО ИнвентаризацияОС.ОсновноеСредство = РегСведПерв.ОсновноеСредство
|ГДЕ
 |ИнвентаризацияОС.Ссылка.ПодразделениеОрганизации = &ПодразделениеОрганизации
 |И РегСведПерв.ИнвентарныйНомер = &ИнвентарныйНомер";


Запрос.УстановитьПараметр(
    "ПодразделениеОрганизации",
    Справочники.ПодразделенияОрганизаций.НайтиПоНаименованию("ПринтерыМосквы")
);

Запрос.УстановитьПараметр(
"ИнвентарныйНомер",
"0481"
);       

РезультатЗапроса = Запрос.Выполнить();
ВыборкаДокументов = РезультатЗапроса.Выбрать();

Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    ИнвНомер = ВыборкаДокументов.ИнвентарныйНомер;
КонецЦикла;


    Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
    Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл
            
        Если ИнвНомер = "0481" Тогда    
          Если Стр.НаличиеФактическое = Истина Тогда
            Стр.НаличиеФактическое = Ложь;
          КонецЕсли;
        КонецЕсли;
        
        Сообщить(Стр.НаличиеФактическое);
        
    КонецЦикла;
```

Данный цикл проставляет галочки всем инвентарным номерам, а не только для номера 0481. Как сделать так, чтобы галочка проставился только для указанного инвентарного номера?

Answer (score 0):

```
Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    ИнвНомер = ВыборкаДокументов.ИнвентарныйНомер;
    // Внутри цикла по документам
    ЭтотДокументНадоОбработать = Истина; // тут фильтруем документы
    Если ЭтотДокументНадоОбработать Тогда
      // Начинаем цикл по табличной части документа
      Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
      Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл
          // Делаем всё что надо ...
          // 
      КонецЦикла;
    КонецЕсли
КонецЦикла;
```

Comment: Галочка все равно везде ставится/убирается. Единственный рабочий вариант пока что такое условие: `Если Стр.ОсновноеСредство = Справочники.ОсновныеСредства.НайтиПоНаименованию(ВыборкаДокументов.ОсновноеСредство) Тогда...`. Т.е. ищем основное средство из регистра сведений. 
А без этого как-то можно, чтобы галочка ставилась только туда, где нужно?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Модифицирую ответ для лучшего понимания
// в запрос добавляем в секцию ВЫБРАТЬ ОС.ОсновноеСредство КАК ОсновноеСредство
ДокументДляОбработки = Неопределено;
МассивОС = Новый Массив;
Пока ВыборкаДокументов.Следующий() Цикл        
    Если ДокументДляОбработки = Неопределено Тогда
      ДокументДляОбработки = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка; // Запоминаем документ
    КонецЕсли;
    Если ДокументДляОбработки = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка Тогда
      // Добавляем в массив все ОС из запроса
      МассивОС.Добавить(ВыборкаДокументов.ОсновноеСредство);
    Иначе
      // Как только изменился документ, вызываем функцию которая ставит галочки
      ПоставитьГалочкиВДокументе(ДокументДляОбработки, МассивОС);
      ДокументДляОбработки = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка; // Запоминаем документ;
      МассивОС = Новый Массив;
      МассивОС.Добавить(ВыборкаДокументов.ОсновноеСредство);
    КонецЕсли;
КонецЦикла;
Если МассивОС.Количество() > 0 Тогда
  ПоставитьГалочкиВДокументе(ДокументДляОбработки, МассивОС);
КонецЕсли;

Процедура ПоставитьГалочкиВДокументе(ДокументДляОбработки, МассивОС)
      // Начинаем цикл по табличной части документа
      Док = ДокументДляОбработки.ПолучитьОбъект();
      Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл
          // Делаем всё что надо ...          
          Если МассивОС.Найти(Стр.ОсновноеСредство) <> Неопределено Тогда
            // Ставим галочку ...
          КонецЕсли;
      КонецЦикла;
      // Записываем документ !
КонецПроцедуры
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде допущена логическая ошибка в условии. Из -за этого проставляет по всем. Правильный код:

```
Док = ВыборкаДокументов.Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
Для каждого Стр из Док.ОС Цикл
        
    //Если ИнвНомер = "0481" Тогда //ошибка, условие всегда будет истина    
    Если Стр.ИнвНомер = ИнвНомер Тогда //проверка на наличие в строке нужного инв. номера.
      Если Стр.НаличиеФактическое = Истина Тогда
        Стр.НаличиеФактическое = Ложь;
      КонецЕсли;
    КонецЕсли;
    
    Сообщить(Стр.НаличиеФактическое);
    
КонецЦикла;
```

Если ИнвНомер = "0481" Тогда - значение переменной вы присвоили ранее, в цикле перебора строк табличной части значение не меняется. Для всех строк получается условие "0481" = "0481"